# A C++17 `std::allocator` implementation

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, memory-management

This is an implementation of C++17 `std::allocator` under the name `my_std::allocator`, with deprecated stuff omitted for simplicity.

```
// A implementation of C++17 std::allocator
// with deprecated members omitted

#include <cstddef>
#include <new>
#include <type_traits>

namespace my_std {

  template <typename T>
  class allocator {
  public:
    using value_type = T;
    using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = std::true_type;
    using is_always_equal = std::true_type;

    allocator() noexcept = default;
    allocator(const allocator&) noexcept = default;
    ~allocator() = default;

    template <class U>
    allocator(const allocator<U>&) noexcept
    {
    }

    T* allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
      if constexpr (alignof(T) > __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__)
        return static_cast<T*>(
          ::operator new(n * sizeof(T), static_cast<std::align_val_t>(alignof(T)))
        );
      else
        return static_cast<T*>(
          ::operator new(n * sizeof(T))
        );
    }

    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n)
    {
      if constexpr (alignof(T) > __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__)
        return ::operator delete(p, n * sizeof(T),
                                 static_cast<std::align_val_t>(alignof(T)));
      else
        return ::operator delete(p, n * sizeof(T));      
    }
  };

  template <class T, class U>
  bool operator==(const allocator<T>&, const allocator<U>&) noexcept
  {
    return true;
  }

  template <class T, class U>
  bool operator!=(const allocator<T>&, const allocator<U>&) noexcept
  {
    return false;
  }

}
```

I have tested it like this:

```
int main()
{
  std::set<std::string, std::less<std::string>,
       my_std::allocator<std::string>> words;

  for (std::string w; std::cin >> w;)
    words.insert(std::move(w));

  for (const auto& w : words)
    std::cout << w << "\n";
}
```

And currently no bug is discovered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `noexcept` on the explicitly defaulted default-ctor and copy-ctor is already implied.
2. Copy-ctor and dtor would be implicitly declared if left out.
3. `.allocate()` (and also `.deallocate()`, but that doesn't matter) fails to check `n * sizeof(T)` for wrap-around.
   Possible Solutions:

   1. Start with a check. This has the advantage of simplicity and broadest conformity.

      ```
      if (n > std::size_t(-1) / sizeof(T))
          throw std::bad_array_new_length();
      ```
   2. Use saturating math, and rely on `::operator new` being unable to allocate `std::size_t(-1)` bytes on (nearly?) all implementations. This is generally more efficient for the common case.

      ```
      auto bytes = n > std::size_t(-1) / sizeof(T) ? std::size_t(-1) : n * sizeof(T);
      ```
4. Because the casts are so simple and obviously right, I would eschew the verbosity of `static_cast`. Guidelines may prohibit it though...
5. I suggest importing the following additional refinements from C++20:

   1. Mark the templated ctor `constexpr`.
   2. Mark `.allocate()`'s return-value `[[nodiscard]]`.
   3. Mark both `operator==` and `operator!=` `constexpr`.